# Golang - Discard as WriteCloser

Tags: go, dev-null

I needed to create an equivalent of [ioutil.Discard](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#pkg-variables) that can satisfy a "WriteCloser" interface. With a bit of Googling I came up with

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type discardCloser struct {
    io.Writer
}

func (discardCloser) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    src := strings.NewReader("Hello world")
    dst := discardCloser{Writer: ioutil.Discard}
    count, err := io.Copy(dst, src)
    fmt.Println(count, err)
    err = dst.Close()
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

[Go playground link here](https://play.golang.org/p/I33-X0Xmpqi)

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Background: some standard library methods return a WriteCloser, such as [net/smtp.Data](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Client.Data). When implementing automated tests, it's nice to be able to exercise functions like this, while sending their output to Discard.

Comment: I think, this is as good as it can get, considering that this is exactly how [`NopCloser`](https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=3458:3499#L100) is implemented in the standard library for `io.Reader`.

Comment: Thank you, that gives me confidence this is probably not too inelegant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took [bereal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770830/bereal)'s tip and looked at `NopCloser`. The approach works nicely, and is useful in test functions built around the libraries that require a `WriteCloser`.

I renamed the type `myWriteCloser` as it can be used to promote "real" writers such as as `&bytes.Buffer`, as well as the special system discard writer.

```
type myWriteCloser struct {
    io.Writer
}

func (myWriteCloser) Close() error {
    return nil
}
```